# Traversing complex XML document in C# with XLinq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

So I want to access the child element in a structure that looks like this:

```
<asdf:foobar attr="value">
    <child>...</child>
</asdf:foobar>
```

I forget what the `asdf` is called, but it is what's causing the problem. My normal method of traversing in XLinq doesn't work:

```
xElem child = xDoc.Element("foobar");
```

Sets `child` to `null` because it claims there is no element `foobar`, and

```
xElem child = xDoc.Element("asdf:foobar");
```

Doesn't work because the compiler whines about the semicolon.

All help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

### UPDATE:

I've been working on a reproduction of this as an example (since I can't show you the actual code). My test code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("BEGIN TEST");

        const string MY_SCHEMA = "http://www.example.com/whatever";

        XElement xTest =
        new XElement("{" + MY_SCHEMA + "}base",
            new XAttribute("{" + XML_STANDARD + "}boofar", MY_SCHEMA),
            new XAttribute("attr1", "val"),
            new XElement("{" + MY_SCHEMA + "}asdf", "ghjkl")
        );

        result.Text = xTest.ToString();

        XElement xOps2 = xTest.Element(XName.Get("asdf", MY_SCHEMA));
        XElement xSubOps2;

        if (xOps2 == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failure.");
        }
        else
        {
            xSubOps2 = xOps2.Element(XName.Get("asdf", MY_SCHEMA));
            MessageBox.Show(xSubOps2.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("END TEST");

        MessageBox.Show("END TEST");
```

This displays the XML that I want:

```
<boofar:base xmlns:boofar="http://www.example.com/whatever" attr1="val">
  <boofar:asdf>ghjkl</boofar:asdf>
</boofar:base>
```

And everything is working great. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the implicit conversion from `string` to `XName` does not parse out the namespace. You need to do this:

```
XName.Get("foobar", "asdf");
```

Comment: `XName.Get("foobar", "asdf").ToString()` returns `{asdf}foobar`, which seems like what I want but is not working out right now. I'll double-check my code for subtle errors and report back.

Comment: The "asdf" bit is called a namespace. Somewhere above that element in the tree there will be an attribute like `xmlns:asdf="http://www.example.com/whatever"`. It's actually the "http://www.example.com/whatever" that you need to pass as the second parameter to `XName.Get` - "asdf" is just an alias, "http://www.example.com/whatever" is the actual namespace.

Comment: Something that I just noticed is that the `xmlns:asdf="http://www.example.com/whatever` part is on the same line as the `<asdf:foobar>` line... might that affect the result?

Comment: No, `xmlns:...="..."` applies to this element and any under it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can handle namespaces is by using the XNamespace class.

```
  XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/whatever";
  XElement child = new XElement(ns + "base");
```